# Runtime Error. Addition of unsigned offset

Tags: c++, runtime-error, unordered-set

I was solving [Increasing Subsequences](https://leetcode.com/problems/increasing-subsequences/) in LeetCode and it is giving error continuously.

Tried in different IDEs with same test cases working every time. Even after brainstorming for an hour or two I was unable to find the error. Here is my C++ solution.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>>ans;
    vector<vector<int>> findSubsequences(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<int>prev;
        calc(nums,prev,0);
        return ans;
    }
     void calc(vector<int>&v, vector<int>&prev, int k)
    {
        if(prev.size()>1)
            ans.push_back(prev);
        if(k<v.size())
        {
            unordered_set<int>s;
            for(int i = k; i < v.size(); i++)
            {
                if((prev.size() == 0 && !s.count(v[i])) || (prev[prev.size()-1]<=v[i] && !s.count(v[i])))
                {
                    prev.push_back(v[i]);
                    calc(v,prev,i+1);
                    s.insert(v[i]);
                    prev.pop_back();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Can anyone please help. Showing error in multiple test cases.

Here I am sharing one of the test cases :
[4,6,7,7]

Error : Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x602000000110 overflowed to 0x60200000010c (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34

Here is the code which is working in IDEs.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<vector<int>>ans;
 void calc(vector<int>&v, vector<int>&prev, int k)
    {
        if(prev.size()>1)
            ans.push_back(prev);
        if(k<v.size())
        {
            unordered_set<int>s;
            for(int i = k; i < v.size(); i++)
            {
                if((prev.size() == 0 && !s.count(v[i])) || (prev[prev.size()-1]<=v[i] && !s.count(v[i])))
                {
                    prev.push_back(v[i]);
                    calc(v,prev,i+1);
                    s.insert(v[i]);
                    prev.pop_back();
                }
            }
        }
    }

int main() {
    vector<int>nums{4,6,7,7};
    vector<int>prev;
    calc(nums,prev,0);
    for(auto i : ans)
    {
        for(auto j : i)
        cout<<j<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: "and it is giving error"  what error ?

Comment: Editing in the solution.

Comment: and please post a [mcve].

Comment: it looks odd that `calc` pushes to the member `ans` but it is never cleared. Calling `findSubsequences` twice will probably not produce the right output

Comment: but why for a single test case it is giving error?

Comment: please post a [mcve]. Code that one can compile and run to reproduce the error. Leetcode uses an ub sanitizer that you can also enable elsewhere

Comment: Really no idea how to do that

Comment: *Really no idea how to do that* . You post a `main`, add includes, etc, same you did when you compiled the code with other IDEs.

Comment: edited in there

Comment: @soumyadip_poddar not related to your problem, but definitely worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the santizer message with the input in the question (see https://godbolt.org/z/j4rxGdoYb). However, this condition may wrap around an unsigned integer:

```
if((prev.size() == 0 && !s.count(v[i])) || (prev[prev.size()-1]<=v[i] && !s.count(v[i])))
```

When `prev.size() == 0` but `!s.count(v[i])` is `false` then `prev.size() -1` subtracts `1` from an unsigned `0`. As a consequence `prev` will be accessed out of bounds.

Either use [`std::ssize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) to get a signed size. Or make sure that `prev[prev.size()-1]` is only evaluated when `prev.size() != 0`.

---

Moreover, the member `ans` is never cleared. I expect to get the wrong answer when you call `findSubsequences` the second time. Also `findSubsequences` should not take the vector by non-const reference when it does not modify it.